# Вывести значения с JSON файла в браузер на js

Tags: javascript, json

Вот код запроса:

```
fetch('./db.json')
    .then(function(data){
     return JSON.stringify(data);
    })
    .then(function(data2){


      console.log(data2);
      for (var item in data2){

  const number = document.createElement('td');
  const user = document.createElement('td');

  console.log(item);
  console.log(item.num)

  number.textContent = `${item.num}`;
  user.textContent = `${item.username}`;

  document.body.append(number, user);

  }
})
```

Вот JSON файл:

```
[{
    "num": 1,
    "username": "user1",
}, {
    "num": 2,
    "username": "user2",
}]
```

Вот ответ браузера в консоли:

```
request.js:8 {}
request.js:17 0
request.js:18 undefined
request.js:17 1
request.js:18 undefined
```

Как мне вывести значения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[там песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?alwaysStrict=false&allowUnusedLabels=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCQBM5jsg3gKGSORAFcBbALhIoCNoAaQ40gZ2hDnImtbClABzJgF98YAJ4AHFBixwAMsD7IAvGkzYA2gF0A3PgD0h5AFoGpoyZgQwCABYAKAOQA6Q%20lquAVqwD2IM4AlFbERK5g9hAgjlAQrFJqAHx4oWFhwDDIsfFSrn4A1kHIcWCkUCAluT7%20MSHG6WEQADbsyJFQfgDuJBA9AKJQnVAugOIggEIggHwgplPIgLwggKwgyOOADCCAXCDBacQi9SZhEVExrPbdAFK1u2bIFuLxYNQEYcdntY5aj43IAERk5F-UAEYmJ9vmwOFwIP9QewoACvsDtgxUiCfhQoQAmBGNL5gioQqE4mHo%20HMIgiHQhMQNcxmfD4GCkEAIMDAALIZ5dc4BRy%20ALUOTYJR8YofIgIAL%20ZoQVzNPyCHkXAxhGB%20KDZABucDVBQgEmQoGQvJAItJ6XFIBUmuapBQ6iNWh1Eh0dJB5pUv3oUH6zTUyHQfgQFGiYFcCDiWAg3og3HALnQwHVwSVnzdYGQuO9vv9gZjIbDEAjUdzcYTSZdKYlfilMrljitNqCycabqr0tl8vr0t%20IVNYQ90G9EQgAA8wABhAKQcC%20gAGqFwndcvxEM6b6QzzSHo4n4GDs-ni9xnG4K4MveI2aD4FctD86AkrjgUhkIHQjn7XuaSI3jfLZPwYhAA)

### IDE

использование продвинутого редактора во многом облегчит изучение, рекомендую VSCode

### fetch

fetch получает в ответ response а не data

- fetch - https://learn.javascript.ru/fetch

### JSON

- JSON.stringify - https://learn.javascript.ru/json#json-stringify
- JSON.parse - https://learn.javascript.ru/json#json-parse

### тут можно запустить

```js
// -,-
// fetch('./db.json')
//     .then(resp => {
//         if (resp.ok) return resp.json()
//         else throw new Error('что-то не так')
//     })
//     .then(showJson)
// - ,-
test: {//     .then(showJson)
    showJson([{
            "num": 1,
            "username": "user1",
        }, {
            "num": 2,
            "username": "user2",
        }]);
}
// -, -
function showJson(json) {
    console.log(json);
    for (var key in json) {
        const value = json[key];
        const numberEl = document.createElement('div');
        const userEl = document.createElement('div');
        console.log(value);
        console.log(value.num);
        numberEl.textContent = `${value.num}`;
        userEl.textContent = `${value.username}`;
        document.body.append(numberEl, userEl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но только что столкнулся с новой проблемой. Я работаю на OpenServer и когда изменяю файл js, сайт почему то не меняется. пробовал и перезапускать сервер, даже компьютер перезагружал. Ничего не помогает, в sources все равно старый js файл. это очень странно, ведь ночью все нормально изменялось. не знаете в чем может быть дело?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb

Answer (score 1):

```
number.textContent = `${data2[item].num}`;
user.textContent = `${data2[item].username}`;
```

Или:

```
for (var item of data2){ }
```